# What does attribute value stand for in input type="image" tag?

Tags: html, forms, input

I know that `alt` is to display info when link to picture isn't correct, `title` is to display info on hover and `name` is to send info where exactly user clicked on that image, but what is use for `value`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#image-button-state-typeimage

Under bookkeeping details for the input element image button state it says:

> The element's value attribute must be
>   omitted.

I.e. don't use it. Any effect of its presence is likely to be browser specific.

Answer (score 2):

The `<input type='image' />` element is a button, and the `value=''` attribute is the value that will be submitted when the user clicks it.

Comment: i can use instead another input type=hidden, is any special profit from doing that in image type?

Comment: @Kuba Werlos: Well, `hidden` is a hidden field, `image` is a button, they're two entirely different things... The first is not shown to the user, the second is shown (the specified image is shown) and the user must click it. It depends on what you want to do.